# Jest - Generate tests with data initialized in beforeAll

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a NestJS API and I'm trying to make a quick integration test that runs through its GET endpoints, in case I'm breaking something without realizing. There are around 80 GET endpoints, so I would like to avoid mantaining the list of endpoints separately as the application continues growing. So I'm listing the routes with `express-routes`, and now having trouble with generating a test for each route. `it.each` complains about receiving undefined, so I assume that the tests are generated before executing the `beforeAll` clause. Is there a good way of sorting out this issue?
Edit: I suppose this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009007/in-jest-how-to-dynamically-generate-tests-based-on-the-api-call-response), but it wasn't resolved and has been inactive for quite a while

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
import { getEndpoints } from "express-routes";

beforeAll(async () => {
  //app initialization omitted for brevity

  routes = getEndpoints(app.getHttpServer()._events.request)
    .filter(route => route.methods.includes("GET")
    .map(route => route.path);
});
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```js
it.each(routes)(`GET %s`, async route => {
  return request(app.getHttpServer()).get(route).expect(200);
});
```

Which gives the error:

```
`.each` must be called with an Array or Tagged Template Literal.

    Instead was called with: undefined
```

I managed to make this work by using a loop inside a single `it` clause, but I'm not comfortable with this solution as it will make it harder for me to diagnose when one of the endpoints fails. This is the working example:

```js
it(`GETS`, async () => {
  for (const route of routes) {
    console.log(route);
    app.getHttpServer())
      .get(route)
      .expect(200);
  }
});
```

Jest's documentation doesn't seem to cover these cases from what I read. Is there a cleaner solution/workaround for this case? Any guidance will be appreciated